# How to prove $a^{p^k}$ is divisible by $p^{k+1}$ but not divisible by $p^{k+2}$

Tags: number-theory

$p$ is prime and odd ,$a$ is divisible by $p$ but not divisible by $p^2$ now how to prove for each 
$k \in {N} $ & $k>1$ , $a^{p^k}$  is divisible by $p^{k+1}$  but not divisible by $p^{k+2}$.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you intend to write $\large a^{p^k}$?

Comment: If $p\mid a$ then $p^{p^k}\mid a^{p^k}$, and assuming $p\gt 1,k\gt 1$ we have $p^k\ge k+2$ which contradicts your statement...

Comment: Saeed: Let me know if I've got the edit to match your question. Your formatting `$a^p$ $^k$` rendered $a^{pk}$

Comment: i'm not familiar with latex i mean a^p^k

Comment: We have $(1):(a^p)^k=a^{pk}$ and also $(2):$ `a^(p^k)`$=a^{p^k}$...

Comment: To write $a^{p^k}$, you can use this `$a^{p^k}$` whereas `$a^k^p$` is ambiguous and doesn't even render.

Comment: I don't think the statement is true with either interpretation of a^p^k.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Yeah, agreed (given $k>1$, at least)

Comment: yeah at least k=2

Comment: It is true ( if $p$ is odd) that if $a-1$ is divisible by $p,$ but not by $p^{2},$ then $a^{p^{k}}-1$ is divisible by $p^{k+1},$ but not by $p^{k+2}$ for all $k \geq 0$. Perhaps this was the question that should have been asked?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\nu_p(n)$ be the greatest integer $\alpha$ such that $p^\alpha$ divides $n$.

It is clear that $\nu_p(n^k)=k\nu_p(n)$ for any positive integers $n,k$. Hence,

$$\nu_p(a^{p^k})=p^k\nu_p(a)=p^k$$

By the way, the condition of that $p$ is odd is superffluous.